# OpenSSL compiled correctly, but can't find while PHP compiles

Tags: php, openssl, command-line-interface

I'm trying to compile PHP7 with latest OpenSSL library. I'm trying this:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32
nmake
nmake test
nmake install
```

Which is installs it at def path, e.g. C:\Program Files\OpenSSL, as manual says.

But when I'm trying to compile the PHP with this files like

```
configure --with-openssl
```

I'm getting a message:

```
PHP Version: 7.1.3

Unknown option --with-openssl; please try configure.js --help for a list of valid options
```

Seems, that there's some troubles in paths, because OpenSSL compiled correctly and tests were passed.

I tried to use my own paths without spaces, but have no result too, also I tried to force specify the dir in --with-openssl="C:\Program Files\OpenSSL" and path without spaces, but gets nothing too(

So in that way which path should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to enable the ssl mod for php in config file

Comment: Ah yes, I'm compiling PHP for CLI. It's not necessary to use php.ini. And it's presents in list when I'm trying to compile it with default openssl extension, but have a errors while compiling, so I'm trying to use the official one.